# Insertar arreglos dinámicos en Mysql y Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

Intento insertar datos dinámicos en MySql, estoy utilizando la versión 10 de Laravel.
Básicamente, el proceso es el siguiente:

- Hago una petición `get` a una API
- Recibo la respuesta y con los datos que recibo, creo dinámicamente la estructura de una tabla
- Inserto los valores en la tabla que se acaba de crear

La tabla siempre se crea correctamente pero la inserción de datos en la tabla solo funciona si recibo un array como este:

[image: Array recurso API posts]

Si el array que recibo contiene otro/s array/s no logro insertar los datos en la tabla. Me lanza una excepción `Array to string conversion.`
Por ejemplo, con un array como este:

[image: Array recurso API users]

Muestro el código que funciona solo en el primer caso

```
class TableController extends Controller
{
    public function getType(array $data,)
    {
        return array_map('gettype', $data);
    }

    public function createTable($tableName)
    {
        $response = Http::client()->get("posts")->json();
        Schema::create($tableName, function (Blueprint $table) use ($response) {
            foreach ($this->getType($response[0]) as $key => $columnType) {
                if ($columnType == 'array') $columnType = 'json';
                if ($key == 'id') $columnType = 'increments';
                $table->$columnType($key);
            }
        });

        $this->insertData($tableName, $response);
    }

    public function insertData($tableName, $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as  $key => $value) {
            DB::table($tableName)->insert([
                $key => $value
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Es importante que pueda insertar los datos recibidos dinámicamente pues cuando utilice la API real, recibiré arrays muy extensos con los que tendré que crear los campos de cada tabla.
Quizás la solución sea más sencilla de lo que pienso, pero lo cierto es que llevo horas intentándolo y hasta ahora sin resultado.
¿Podrían dar alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?
Gracias

Comment: Que significa _"no logro insertar los datos en la tabla."_? Te lanza una excepción o solo no inserta los datos en esa columna?

Comment: No puedes conocer el formato de la tabla o tablas antes de llamar a la API? Es muy raro, no tiene mucho sentido que cuando llames a la API te devuelva arrays distintos... Cómo haces la llamada a esa API? (Pon un ejemplo de endpoint)

Comment: @porloscerros tienes razón es ambiguo como lo he dicho, lanza una excepción, Array to string convertion, pero no soy capaz de dar con la solución aún haciendo foreach para recorrer el array.

Comment: @Jakala cada imagen se corresponde con una petición distinta. La primera imagen se corresponde a cuando  llamo al recurso posts. La segunda cuando llamo al recurso users. Por así decirlo, cuando recibo un array simple(posts), inserto los datos en la tabla sin problemas, cuando el array contiene otro/s array/s (users), es cuando tengo el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería usar un mutator, o mejor, un castable, para normalizar los datos desde tu api hacia la BBDD. Sin embargo, como estás usando el query builder a secas y no eloquent, esas opciones no están sobre la mesa. Lo que te queda en cambio es serializar los arrays:

```
public function insertData($tableName, $data)
{
    foreach ($data as  $key => $value) {
        DB::table($tableName)->insert([
            $key =>  is_scalar($value)? $value : json_encode($value)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: He probado tu código pero sigue lanzando la excepción Array to string conversion. He probado con foreach, for, array_map('is_scalar, $value) y otras pero el resultado siempre es el mismo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as  $key => $value) {
        DB::table($tableName)->insert([
            $key => implode(","$value)
        ]);
    }
```

Para obtener el valor utilizas un explode

```
    foreach ($data as  $key => $value) {
        DB::table($tableName)->insert([
            $key => json_encode($value) ? json_encode($value) : ""
        ]);
    }
```

Para obtener el valor utilizas un json_decode

```
    foreach ($data as  $key => $value) {
        DB::table($tableName)->insert([
            $key => serialize($value)
        ]);
    }
```

Para obtener el valor utilizas un unserialize

Recuerda tambien que puedes utilizar la funcion is_array() de php para validar solo los resultados que sean un arreglo y aplicar el metodo que mas te guste

```
 foreach ($data as  $key => $value) {
        DB::table($tableName)->insert([
            $key => is_array($value) ? serialize($value) : $value
        ]);
    }
```

Tambien asegurate que la columna tenga el suficiente espacio para guardar la info ya que al serializar pueden ser strings muy largos